# How to make R data.table throw an error when recycling in a column assignment like data.frame?

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to make data.table follow the same rules as data.frame for recycling?

I do not want to recycle as most of the times it s a bug in the code.
Is there an option in data.table to achieve this
(setting warnings as an error  is not an option...)

```
> df <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
> df$b <- 1:9
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, b, value = 1:9) : 
  replacement has 9 rows, data has 10
> require(data.table)
> df <- data.table(a = 1:10)
> df$b <- 1:9
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
   Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'b' (recycled 
   leaving remainder of 1 items).
```

Comment: If such an option existed, I suspect it would have been mentioned here: [recycle-remainder warning in as.data.table and data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/362), or found among [the other options](https://github.com/cran/data.table/blob/608958201639620bb5bf5b6fd5d438d95e58e2ce/R/onLoad.R#L30-L50). (maybe maybe you need to change the code around [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R#L122)?)

Comment: Thank you was looking for some related issue. Ok l guess I need to avoid that construct then :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your desires are not well motivated, but you could wrap all of you code with something like this:

```
withCallingHandlers({
                      warning("some other warning")
                      print("some code we get to")
                      df[, b := 1:7]
                      print("the rest of your code we don't get to")
                    },
                    warning = function(w) {
                      if(grepl("data.table", w$call[[1]])) stop(w$message)
                    })
#[1] "some code we get to"
#Error in (function (w)  : 
#  Supplied 7 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'b' (recycled leaving #remainder of 3 items).
#In addition: Warning message:
#In withCallingHandlers({ : some other warning
```

Along the same lines of thought, you could also try the following:

```
options( warning.expression = {substitute({
           tr = traceback(5)
           if (grepl("data.table", tr[[1]]))
             stop("data.table warning converted to error")
         })})
{warning('test'); print('get here'); df[, b := 1:7]; print('but not here')}
#1: warning("test") at #1
#[1] "get here"
#2: `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(b, 1:7)) at #1
#1: df[, `:=`(b, 1:7)] at #1
#Error in doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart) : 
#  data.table warning converted to error
```

As always when dealing with this kind of low level analysis of expressions - be warned, there may be dragons.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Henrik makes it look like you can't. But there's nothing stopping you from adding tests in to your code, to have peace of mind e.g.

```
mySet <- function(df, j, value){
  testthat::expect_true(nrow(df) == length(value), "Number of rows are not equal")
  set(df, j=j, value=value)
  return(df)
} 

# original warning
df$b <- 1:9
# errors
mySet(df, "c", 1:9)
# passes
mySet(df, "d", 1:10)[]
```